# datagridview export to excel not showing the last row in excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export, rows

I'm exporting a datagridview to Excel using a button's click event. The data is exporting  but the last row of the table is not appearing. I've played with my code but I'm unable to figure out the problem. If someone would help me I would be grateful.

```
private void button34_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new    
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Workbook wb = Excel.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
    Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)Excel.ActiveSheet;
    Excel.Visible = true;
    ws.Cells[1, 1] = "VehiclePlateNumber";
    ws.Cells[1, 2] = "VehicleDescription";
    ws.Cells[1, 3] = "DeviceCode";
    ws.Cells[1, 4] = "DriverName";
    ws.Cells[1, 5] = "DriverKeyTag";

    for (int j = 2; j <= datagridview9.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[j, i] = datagridview9.Rows[j - 2].Cells[i - 1].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The final row that you export is datagridview9.Rows.Count - 2 (from the max value of your for loop and the Rows[j-2] reference). This is obviously the second to last row.

Comment: Btw, the question by itself is fine, but as it looks like a simple typo, I've flagged to close it as it's unlikely to be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change it to following statement and check once

> for (int j = 2; j <= datagridview9.Rows.Count+1; j++)